# How do I get the 3d coordinates of my model Instance? [LibGDX]

Tags: java, libgdx, 3d, coordinates

I want to get the 3d coordinates (as a Vector3) from my model Instances.
with the following code I can only get the original coordinates, but in the render method, my model is rotating around the Y-axis (and moving at the same time) and I want to get its coordinates each frame.
I'm using a little class created by @Xoppa :

```
public static class GameObject extends ModelInstance {
    public Vector3 center = new Vector3();
    public Vector3 dimensions = new Vector3();
    public float radius;

    public BoundingBox bounds = new BoundingBox();

    public GameObject (Model model, String rootNode, boolean mergeTransform) {
        super(model, rootNode, mergeTransform);
        calculateBoundingBox(bounds);
        bounds.getCenter(center);
        bounds.getDimensions(dimensions);
        radius = dimensions.len() / 2f;
    }
}
```

and here's my code:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    super.render(delta);
    if (loading && manager.update()) {
        doneLoading();
    }

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    backgroundSprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();

    for(GameObject instance : instances){
        instance.transform.rotate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 0.5f);
        float x = instance.bounds.getCenterX();
        float y = instance.bounds.getCenterY();
        float z = instance.bounds.getCenterZ();
        System.out.println(x+" "+y+" "+z);
        if(isVisible(cam, instance)){
            modelBatch.begin(cam);
            modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
            modelBatch.end();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help, there's no function "getPosition" or sth like that, it's all about Matrix4 and I have never had a math course about it. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
Vector3 position;
position = modelInstance.transform.getTranslation(new Vector3());
```

This gets the position and stores it in the `position` vector.

---

Sometimes you might have to transform the transform with the view and projection matrix to get the correct result.

```
/* Make sure that you use a new Matrix4, otherwise you will 
   change the models transform, which we don't want to do. */
Matrix4 modelTransform = new Matrix4();
modelTransform.set(modelInstance.transform);
/* Multiply the transform with the combined matrix of the camera. */
modelTransform.mul(camera.combined);
/* Extract the position as usual. */
Vector3 position;
position = modelTransform.getTranslation(new Vector3());
```

This gets the position and stores it in the `position` vector and the transform and stores it in the `modelTransform` matrix. You should probably re-use this vector and matrix every time you get the position instead of creating new ones.